# Truncate GridView Column Header Text by CSS

Tags: asp.net, css, gridview, aspxgridview

I put this style in the ASP header

```
<style type="text/css">
    .truncated
    {
        white-space: nowrap;
        overflow: hidden;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
    }
</style>
```

and applied it to GridView cell

```
<CellStyle CssClass="truncated"></CellStyle>
```

It works fine.

However, when I tried to apply the same style to header

```
<HeaderStyle CssClass="truncated"></HeaderStyle>
```

It fails.
I suppose the overflow text in column header (text length exceeds the column width) can be truncated as: abcdef -> abcd...
But the overflow text only hidden, no ellipsis effect appear, i.e. no "..." appear.

Any ideas regarding to this issue or any other suggestions for the solution? Thanks!

Comment: "It fails." ? What does that mean exactly?

Comment: Sorry for the unclear explanations.
I suppose the overflow text in the column header can be truncated as: abcdefg -> abcd... (somethings like that). But the text only hidden, no ellipsis effect, i.e. not "..." appear

Comment: Dude, keep in mind, when someone here says "What do you mean" and criticize your statements, they probably don't know the answer at all. Who knows the answer doesn't get stuck with such simple words. It's like a form of trolling here.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a width to the .truncated ruleset (or a max-width).

Answer (score 0):

It happens cuz HeaderStyle apply style to the header row not particular cells of header. In order to apply styling to header cells change your style to:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .truncated th
    {
        white-space: nowrap;
        overflow: hidden;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
        width: 50px;
        display: inline-block;
    }
</style>
```

Ofc you can adjust width to your needs.